# Regex: Matching digits that start with 4-9?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Below is my current command with the output. The problem is the line starting with a 2. How can I incorporate to only match lines starting with 4-9?

```
grep -o -P '(?:(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d))' * | sort -u
20100101
71160868
71161452
```

The grep source is an email so its pretty messy to post here.

Comment: The regex for 4-9 is `[4-9]`, if that's what you ask

Comment: Yea I know that, but I am unsure where that needs to go in my regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -oP '(?:(?<!\d)[4-9]\d{7}(?!\d))' * | sort -u
```

`[4-9]` will match only if first digit is between 4 and 9 followed by any 7 digits.

Comment: Because the first digit of `\d{8}` is now matched by `[4-9]`. Otherwise you'd now get 9-digit numbers.